# Jquery-UI dynamically increment the date from datepicker calendar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I created `two calendars` with datepicker from jquery ui and I want to change the selected day from the `second calendar` according to the selected date from the `first calendar`. For example, if I select `5/21/2016` from the first calendar, then when I click on the second input field to open the second calendar I need this calendar to dynamically change its selected date to `first calendar selected day` + `4 days`

This is my code:

```
<input class="datepicker begin" type="text" />
<input class="datepicker end" type="text"/>

    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker.begin").datepicker({
            minDate: '+2d',
            maxDate: '+2y'
        })
        $(".datepicker.end").datepicker({
            minDate: '+4d',
            maxDate: '+2y'
        });
    });
```

The above code should be changed to something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker.begin").datepicker({
        minDate: '+2d',
        maxDate: '+2y'
    })
    $(".datepicker.end").datepicker({
        minDate: $(".datepicker.begin") + 4d,
        maxDate: '+2y'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) function for your first date picker in order to set the value of your second :

```
$(".datepicker.begin").datepicker({
        minDate: '+2d',
        maxDate: '+2y',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
           // Resolve the current date
           var begin = new Date($(this).val());
           var d = begin.getDate();
           var m = begin.getMonth();
           var y = begin.getFullYear();
           // Update your target date in your other date picker
           $(".datepicker.end").datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m, d+2));
        }
});
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/husifi/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: That works great! Can I set to inactive all the days that have passed from the second calendar? Ex: when the date 5/16/2016 is selected from the second calendar I should not be able to select the date 5/15/2016 if I want to change this date.

Comment: Sure, you could set the `minDate` for your second picker to ensure it didn't exceed the value of your first one as seen in [this updated example](http://jsbin.com/husifi/2/edit?html,output).